# Excel to copy realtime data and create a chart out of it

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I am very new to VBA programming.

I have a excel sheet where real time data is populated to a  cell say for example Sheet1.A6   everysecond.

I am in need  of a macro which will run every 1 minute  to copy the Sheet1.A6 value to another sheet along with timestamp  like value in Sheet2.A and timestamp in Sheet2.B .

Sheet2 Output will be like

**Value *   Time**

23.1    *    11:00 AM

22.5    *   11:01 AM

22.6    *   11:02 AM

.......... 
.............

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `Worksheet.Change` event is your first port of call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want some code to run every minute.

You should be able to do this with the [Application.OnTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195809%28v=office.11%29.aspx) function.

Here are a couple of references and examples:

- [Ozgrid Excel MVP: Run macro on time](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/run-macro-on-time)
- [Excel Experts - run code very hour, minute, second](http://excelexperts.com/vba-tips-run-code-every-hour-minute-or-second)

First create your procedure which will copy the cell to the destination sheet.

Then in a normal module you can call it like this:

```
Sub SetTimeForCopy()
    dim nextTime as date
    nextTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CopyValue"
End Sub
```

copy the value over like this:

```
Sub CopyValue()
    application.Calculate
    worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row+1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value
    Call SetTimeForCopy' call the schedule code again
End Sub
```

**NOTICE** that in *CopyValue* the *SetTimeForCopy* procedure is called which will schedule the next copy.

Comment: Hi thanks for the code but this line
"  worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c7").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value  "

will it not copy to the same cell again in the next run ?

Comment: @Chandru yes, you need to determine the next row down using `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` (returns the last used row) and you increment by 1.

Comment: Hello Philip its not working. Its copying the value to the same row :(

Comment: @Chandru: I have modified my code, copy it again, then put a breakpoint on the line where it puts in the value, then when it stops you can see the row number and find out what's happening

Comment: I used a counter varaible i.
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value
This line worked . Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why are you moving the real time data point? Use a variable to identify the computed location for each successive entry.[You can use the OFFSET and COUNTA functions to re-compute the cell location of the variable.] Use the Worksheet.Change event to generate timestamp value in an adjacent cell.